# I have low reputation right now; what do I do when an answer I ask to get converted to a comment gets deleted instead?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

I recently spotted an interesting comment in the question "[Tiny javascript implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384762/tiny-javascript-implementation/23389243#23389243)" referring to the seemingly-existent lightweight "Jsi" JavaScript implementation. I couldn't find anything about the referenced information on the 'Net anywhere, so I gave up and came back to SO to ask the comment poster what he was referring to.

My SO reputation is too low to comment at the moment because I don't exactly have the patience, energy or time (in that order, actually) to answer enough questions to boost it up so I *could* answer (which has proven very frustrating on multiple occasions).

Also, at the time of writing, the comment in question is this particular user's sole item of interaction with StackExchange thus far. I also didn't find an email address or other contact information listed on this person's profile page. It seemed that it would be impossible to communicate with this person.

Then I realized that it wouldn't be common sense for there not to be an option for moderators to convert answers to comments for edge cases like this <kbd>(Self-)**EDIT:** This is not done for low-rep users, under any circumstances)</kbd>, so I posted an my comment to the question in the form of an answer with a polite request at the top for a moderator to convert it to a comment, and waited.

Today I was greeted with this... now what do I do, both in this particular context, and in the long term? (This situation doesn't magically give me more patience, time or energy to up my so-called "reputation".)

[image: Screenshot of deleted post]

Comment: Note that the answer wasn't deleted by a moderator, it was deleted by the community via a review task. Even if a moderator had reviewed it, though, we don't convert answers to comments for low-rep users ever. It still would have just been deleted.

Comment: what is unclear in the comment under your ["answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/not-an-answer/info) in the scren shot?

Comment: **@animuson**: I didn't know it was deleted by the community - the site appears to put the "blame" on a single user (as visible in my screenshot; not sure if you see anything different). And I didn't know about not converting low-rep users' answers to comments.  **@gnat**: Nothing, I was just initially jolted that the question was deleted without a contextual explanation.

Comment: @i336_ edit 25 questions and/or answers, and you'll get 50 rep, enough to post comments. There are plenty of posts on [main] that need improvement in spelling and grammar. Just make sure that you make each edit count.

Comment: @animuson - I wouldn't necessarily say we never do it. If the comment adds value to the question or an answer, I'll convert, no matter the reputation of the person involved.

Comment: Funny, posting this Meta question has fixed your problem both by getting the comment posted, *and* putting you over 50 rep!

Comment: @animuson This must be a StackOverflow-only rule, as I see it being done quite often on other SEs.

Comment: Why are you concerned with SO reputation? Who cares?

Comment: @animuson I saw a mod on [android.se] convert a low-rep user's answer to a comment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I posted the comment for you.

I realize this limitation sucks, but there are good arguments for having it in place.

Don't worry, though - I'm sure you'll easily reach the required 50 points.

See also: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)

Comment: BTW, you can always comment on your own posts or answers to your own posts. You could have done that in the picture, as I see an "Add Comment" button.

Comment: @tbodt: The picture shows that he has over 100 reputation NOW.  Add comment was not available on that post before he got sufficient reputation, neither the question nor answer under discussion were his.

Comment: I disagree that there are good reasons. It seems to me that if someone does not have enough "trust" to post a comment - which are meant to be to ask for clarification - then they should not have enough "trust" to actually provide an answer. It seems almost every new user ends up using an answer to actually make a comment or ask for clarification etc.... And then gets downvoted. It is very discouraging.

Comment: @mjs  it's not an ideal situation, but read the arguments in the link provided above. There's a much better system in place to clean up answers than there is for comments.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then the system should be improved for comments rather than penalising new users for attempting to actually engage in the community.

Comment: The issue of allowing new users to post comments is twofold: It discourages new users from being involved and providing answers to questions, *and* it encourages them to begin a conversation in the comments - a common problem even among 50+ rep users.  It's a low-bar threshhold specifically to make sure only users who are really interested in helping/seeking help join the conversation.

Comment: @mjs: Material from low-reputation users is subject to moderation before it gets posted.  Allowing low-rep users to comment would require that either low-rep comments be posted without moderation, or that moderators spend time reviewing comments.

Comment: @mjs - a few months later ... I thought along similar lines re comments not allowed with low rep - it sort of bugged me too for the same reasons you mention: that it prevented me from engaging. However, having done enough moderation elsewhere made me step back and think 'well, I'm new here, don't know the ropes - and those who've made these rules probably have well founded reasons for them.'  Learned some ropes - and what do you know - in a very brief time, I had passed 50 and could engage - and with more finesse because I understood better. So now I agree with the limitation.