# Low rep with answers converted to comments, how to respond to follow-up comments/questions

Tags: discussion, support

I had an answer that was automatically converted to a comment as a "trivial answer" to this question: ["is not a valid win32 application" on windows xp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314217/is-not-a-valid-win32-application-on-windows-xp) .  When the OP asked me a follow-up question, I could not reply as I do not have enough rep to reply in the comments.

How do I approach this?

I have read [I have low reputation right now; what do I do when an answer I ask to get converted to a comment gets deleted instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253960/i-have-low-reputation-right-now-what-do-i-do-when-an-answer-i-ask-to-get-conver) in which the solution was another user posting the comment for someone, which doesn't really seem like a solution.  I have also read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174) and I understand why the 50 rep comment limitation is in place.

But in this case I was not trying to comment, and with the automatic conversion to comment combined with the rep limitation what is the appropriate protocol here?  I ended up replying with an answer, but that seems like a poor workaround which will eventually get down-voted or deleted (lowering my rep and limiting my participation options even more).

**Edit**: I am asking about how to deal with this very specific situation that is not addressed in any other questions I could find.  It is not a general "How do I gain rep on SO?" question.

Comment: I have seen your answer, and IMHO you should have cited and fleshed out something about this _useful link_ to make it an answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are undoubtedly correct, it should have been a fuller answer and I will not make that mistake again.  But given that it was not and this is the situation that occurred, I want to know how to respond appropriately.

Comment: _"I want to know how to respond appropriately."_ As long you cannot comment, give full, correct, concise and useful answers. This will even gain you enough rep for commenting (in unsure cases) soon.